# Python send data and jpg via http

Tags: python, image, post

I would like to send data to a server via http and include some parameters and a picture.

Has anyone managed to do this with Python?

I am using a Raspberry Pi so I have python 2.7.3.

Many thanks for your help,

John.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with the [Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) lib (from [doc](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)):

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
>>> r.text
{
  ...
  "files": {
    "file": "<censored...binary...data>"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file